# Mapster and list to dictionary System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key'

Tags: dictionary, mapster

I have an issue where my mapping for a List to Dictionary won't map the Name to the Key property.  The Value does fine.  The implementation is below.  System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key'

**Implementation**

```
_mapper.Map<List<MetaModel>, Dictionary<string, object>>(model.MemberPaymentVendor.Meta)
```

**Config**

```
config.NewConfig<MetaModel, KeyValuePair<string, object>>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(x.Name, x.Value));

       config.NewConfig<List<MetaModel>, Dictionary<string, object>>()
                 .MapWith(s => ToDictionary<MetaModel>(s));
    
public static Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary<T>(List<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();

        return source.Select(v => v.Adapt<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to figure out its reason, I caught it with the following simple example.

```
var x = new KeyValuePair<string, object>();
var y = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
y.Add(x);
y.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value); // <--- Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
```

Did you see what can be incurred here?

```
return source.Select(v => v.Adapt<KeyValuePair<string, object>>()).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about.  There is an issue with Mapster and Adapt not translating the key over.

Comment: It maybe clear, but has NOTHING to do with my question.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I advise you to learn C# Linq.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# Linq but Mapster and how it maps.